# Regular Expression to extract data between two bracket

Tags: java, regex, string

For example I have a string line as follows

```
What is your family Occupation? [RMB 2011]
```

I want to extract two data from here.

- RMB
- 2011

The RMB part can be of any length. I have used following regex pattern to extract the data

```
^[(\[][A-Z]{3}\s\d\d\d\d[)\]]$
```

But it does not match anything in the string. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need the string start with `]`. Try this [online](https://regex101.com/r/1D08Op/1):

```
\[([A-Z]{3})\s(\d{4})\]
```

And if *RMB part can be of any length*, you can change `[A-Z]{3}` to `[A-Z]{1,}`.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted :). Thanks